# Alternative for google maps API

Tags: ios, google-maps

I work with google maps API to trace the itinerary between two points at the moment, i can see that this API is so standard besides it's the iPhone version of what we use to see in the web model, so i want to use either another google API which seems more "beautiful" or another API, can you please give me some advices?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you want another API. Are you asking if there are any others that are commonly used out there? Or are you saying there's something in particular that bothers you about this one? If the latter - what is it that bothers you?

Answer (score 3):

Check OpenStreetMap. They have different kinds of APIs, and many projects to make them accessible to certain languages natively. I collected **[some links here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1104879/321143)**. CloudMade, that I mention in that answer, has objective-c in their collection.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the Bing Maps API?>  I used it a project last year it sounds like it may be the ticket you need.

http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx

Comment: Hi, did you use it in iPhone application?