# Parsing geo data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, geo

I have list of addresses. For each of them I need to find amount of schools, parks, shops in 500 m radius. What is the fastest and most convenient way to do it for someone who was never into programming, but I do know python syntax and already solved some problems in Python.

I have found Google API, that I think I can't buy, I have found map quest API, but It's not very useful.

Comment: OpenStreetMap is another possible resource - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095419/is-there-an-api-for-openstreetmap

Answer (score 0):

You can use googles places api: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/nearby-search with radius and filter on lots of different types.

You need a google-api-key and you get >$200 each month free, it is about 6000 reqs/month. If you add out a service it can be expensive.

Openstreetmap have the overpass api: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example.

But there are way too few objects in the openstreetmap database for my part of the world (oslo/norway), for it to become useful. So I have little experience her, but it is used by services like `https://beeline.co/` in their velo2 navigation units. I've heard London is greatly mapped.